# Why does 0.0.0.0 resolve to the loopback device?

Tags: loopback

Why does 0.0.0.0 resolve to the loopback device?

```
$ curl --verbose 0.0.0.0
* Rebuilt URL to: 0.0.0.0/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 0.0.0.0...
* Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
```

Answer (score 3):

It follows from an RFC requirement.  [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) says:

> 3. Global and Other Specialized Address Blocks
>
> 0.0.0.0/8 - Addresses in this block refer to source hosts on "this"
> network.  **Address 0.0.0.0/32 may be used as a source address for this
> host on this network**; other addresses within 0.0.0.0/8 may be used to
> refer to specified hosts on this network

That given, the only rational thing to do with `0.0.0.0` as a destination is to treat it likewise.  You can't route it anywhere else, because return packets would violate the RFC; you can't say it's invalid, because it's not when used as a source; the only sane thing to do with it when used as a destination is map it to `localhost` as well.

One of my old colleagues used to use `telnet 0 22` as a real timesaver for `telnet localhost 22`.

Comment: The quote above sounds like it's talking about using `0.0.0.0` as a source address, as opposed to a destination address.

Comment: It is; see my expanded comment above.